# UITableView selecting section header

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm getting weird behaviour in my `TableView`

I turned `isUserInteractionEnabled` on one of my section headers because I need to put a `collectionView` in it. Before I did anything I noticed that when I tap on that header view (it is a `UITableViewCell`) it triggers the `didSelectRowAt` method with the index of a first cell in that section (right below the header). Does anybody know what causes that behaviour and how to turn it off?

Comment: can you show `viewForHeaderInSection` method?

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: My viewForHeaderInSection is very simple. It is just: 

'let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "MenuSectionTitle") as! MenuHeaderTableViewCell
            cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            return cell'

Comment: `MenuHeaderTableViewCell` is `UITableViewCell` or `UIView`?

Comment: UITableViewCell

Comment: If you want to put `UICollectionView` in `tableView` section header then I suggest you to create 1 `UIView` class and inside that add `UICollectionView` and load that class in `viewForHeaderInSection`.

Answer (score -2):

Your header sections are part of your UITableView.

```
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath){
}
```

- In this method indexPath return rows and section, indexPath.section
  -> returns section of UitableView, you have tapped and indexPath.row -> returns down of that particular section, tapped.
- So this function is going to get called no matter what you do. You
  need to override    the table view's gesture to avoid this.

Comment: So this is intended behaviour? Can I detect in didSelectRowAt that the header was selected and not the cell?

Comment: @PawełZgoda-Ferchmin, no you cant

Comment: Thats great. Can You tell me how?

Comment: Yes, Please take UIView in ViewInHeader instead of UiTableViewCell.

Comment: @PawełZgoda-Ferchmin, sorry for my misunderstanding but you can't check this in `didSelectRowAt`. it's for row you need to do the thing that I mentioned in comment.